# Target specific value of a node with jQuery

Tags: jquery, targeting

OK, I basically have the following scenario with some dynamically generated html:

```
<div id = "main-hold">
    <ul class="main-class">
        <li class="item">
        <a tabindex="-50" title="Title 1" class="class aa" id="12365" href="#" target="">Learning outcomes<div class="end-icon"></div></a>
```

...

Basically I want to be able to show/hide objects of class "item" using the unique id referenced within, but am struggling to target it.  Any thoughts appreciated

```
$("#main-hold").hide();
```

Successfully hides everything, but I haven't been able to drill down to the id level.

Comment: Is it the `li` elements you want to hide or `a` elements in them? If `li`s do they all have the class `item`?

Comment: Hi, Yes, they are all of class item, so I thought the unique id would be the best option to target individuals.  To hide the a elements in them would be sufficient.

Comment: What unique ID are you referring to? In response to **WHAT** event would you like to hide/show individual `li.item` elements? You may probably have to give us more code than you have given us ... Give us some context.

Comment: Sorry, so from the snippet above, if you can imagining it continuing on like <li class="item">...<li> with many items, the a element of each of which will be identical to the one above but with just different content.  The id="12365" in the one above will be unique to each "item" so I thought that targeting this would be an easy way to show/hide specific items.  And sorry, it is in response to buttons clicks that I would like to show hide these specific items, the clicks of which I can currently successfully capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this one, hope this help :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item #12365').hide();

   $('#main-hold').on('click','.item', function(){
      $('.item #12365').toggle();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These are your possibilities:

Hide all elements of class `item`

```
$(".item").hide();
```

Hide all elements of class `item` that are a child of `#main-hold`:

```
$("#main-hold .item").hide();
```

Hide all elements of class `item` that are a **DIRECT** child of `#main-hold` (this isn't the case for you, but wanted to add for clarity):

```
$("#main-hold > .item").hide();
```

Hide all elements of class `item` that are of type `li` and are a child of `#main-hold`:

```
$("#main-hold li.item").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understood, you somehow know the unique id of items, you want to hide...
if your html is always like that - and the id is a child element of item, you would do it like that:

```
$("#theDesiredID").parent().hide();
```